# Textarea value submitted as empty value

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I am trying to save value from textarea input to the string property in the model. Textarea field is created like this

```
<div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4" style="font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-6" title="Tooltip text">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.StringProp, new { @class = "full-text-area" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

String property is defined in a model as:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string StringProp { get; set; }
```

When form is submitted, value sent is empty no matter what is typed in the textarea. If `TextAreaFor` is replaced by `EditorFor` then value is submitted correctly but I need multi line input. If I manually set StringProp value, it is shown correctly. I am not sure what am I doing wrong so it keeps posting empty value?

Comment: is it wrapped into a `<form>` tag?

Comment: @Andrei yes, it is inside of the form

Comment: can you show me your controller?

Comment: @Andrei thanks for trying to help, finally I found what was the issue and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (and luckily) it is my oversight - I saw that form is submitted through JS and never looked in the details there since all form fields are shown in POST request.

What happened is that someone who wrote this code before gathered form fields data and there was an error in the part where text area values are gathered, so values were always undefined.

So I guess the real answer is

> Read your code carefully and don't assume things